# How to Post Transaction in Bitcoin Network?

Tags: network, raw-transaction, transaction-id

I need help here as it has been almost a week since I've been trying to figure this out. Fyi, I can get my Python Script running using "Mainnet" for Bitcoin Transaction that able to execute and produce the following results:
Tx ID:`8b547dd1e6393b4279afe6e083b3b563b929d09ab5bfdbf55c773c84af10b047`

`bc1qelvkpyjqc6j4smr5n4mscn86pphuv5nxugnvz9`  --> P2WPKH Receiving Address

Raw transaction:

```
0200000001ff67938803c97f765e89dfe81522a20569a38f60b911daa58f4e97ca0ed3d2130000000000ffffffff01a0bb0d00000000001976a914cfd9609240c6a5586c749d770c4cfa086fc6526688ac00000000
```

Raw signed transaction:

```
02000000000101ff67938803c97f765e89dfe81522a20569a38f60b911daa58f4e97ca0ed3d2130000000000ffffffff01a0bb0d00000000001976a914cfd9609240c6a5586c749d770c4cfa086fc6526688ac02473044022023c2275892a7d85996a9578e9310122e63f9b4c89b25062a9bbc28ca2891524802206fc32e53a346fcfb41cf0193c5ddfcfad0f240593fdf95a3eda624ff4e25fe7f012102e365c048d44d323ef7ece0084b7ea403758c650a990092002375588c412377fe00000000
```

However, when I check the above Tax ID, is not in the Blockchain Explorer due to in my Python Script (that's where I've run this it does not "SET" or "POST" into Bitcoin Network)

I do need guidance on how to connect or post my Python Bitcoin Transaction Script to the Bitcoin Network?

My apology as I'm not an expert and I'm quite a nerd but who is willing to learn.

Appreciate your kind guidance on my situation here.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo - sorry to make you confused, My goal is to Run the Script in conjunction with having connected to Bitcoin Network so that my TXID is posted and the transaction goes through.

Comment: Your transaction is trying to spend an output (13d2d30eca974e8fa5da11b9608fa36905a22215e8df895e767fc903889367ff:0) that does not exist (and never existed as far as I can see), so this cannot work. How did you construct the transaction?

Comment: @PieterWuile I run that using Atom Editor without connecting to rpc_user and rpc_password. This is why in the Blockchain Explorer, it does not have or exist.

Comment: What editor you use isn't relevant. What program did you use to construct the transaction? It is invalid.

Comment: @PieterWuille Sorry, I'm using Python running inside Atom Editor. I forked this from Github --> https://github.com/jsim77/python-bitcoin-utils    About what program I use? That's the above I have. If you mentioned that this is invalid, can you guide me? to be honest, I'm no expert but still learning.